# Import style guide settings to intelliJ?

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea

I'd like to use the code [style guide](https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide) settings for a project like Databricks has on GitHub. Is there any way to do so? Sort of like a file that will set up my IDE (IntelliJ) instead of me manually having to read the guide and set every setting. It seems like I would miss something since the guide is so long.

Comment: Do you have settings file? If yes, try to import it in Settings->Editor->Code styles (choose desired lang).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the **Checkstyle** plugin for IntelliJ. With this one you can import a set of code styling definition.

[Checkstyle Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065-checkstyle-idea)

[Example Google Java Style Guide](http://www.practicesofmastery.com/post/intellij-checkstyle-google-java-style-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

You can import settings into IntelliJ to apply the code settings. However I can't find such file at the link you provided.

However, should you be able to get your hands on it, you can import it as follows:
[image: Screenshot how to import settings]

This will change the settings of your IDE to those defined in the style guide settings you imported. Next time you format your code for example, it will be formatted according to your new settings.